# Where does pip finds a cached wheel if it is not in pip's cache dir?

Tags: python, caching, pip

I have a clean Python virtual environment `txtex`. In this env I check what's in the pip cache:

```
(txtex) $ pip cache list
Cache contents:

 - cffi-1.16.0-cp38-cp38-macosx_13_0_arm64.whl (176 kB)
 - xattr-0.10.1-cp312-cp312-macosx_13_0_arm64.whl (15 kB)
```

This indicates that cache files are independent of the venv. So far so good.

Now I install into this venv a package which in turn installs the dependency `typing_extension`:

```
(txtex) $ pip install pypdf
Collecting pypdf
  Downloading pypdf-4.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (286 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 286.1/286.1 kB 4.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00Collecting typing_extensions>=3.7.4.3
  Using cached typing_extensions-4.10.0-py3-none-any.whl (33 kB)
Installing collected packages: typing_extensions, pypdf
Successfully installed pypdf-4.1.0 typing_extensions-4.10.0
```

The output "*Using cached typing_extensions...*" clearly indicates that `typing_extensions` was in the cache. But neither before inor afterwards is it in the designated cache. If I ask pip *again* for the files in the cache I get only the old unrelated wheels:

```
(txtex) $ pip cache list
Cache contents:

 - cffi-1.16.0-cp38-cp38-macosx_13_0_arm64.whl (176 kB)
 - xattr-0.10.1-cp312-cp312-macosx_13_0_arm64.whl (15 kB)
```

Also I checked under the location `~/Library/Caches/pip` (which is what `pip cache dir` prints), the only wheel files are the unrelated locally built ones.

Where did `pip install` get the cached `typing_extensions-4.10.0-py3-none-any.whl` file from?